# Unable to delete file using cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am saving my file here : `/storage/emulated/0/myApp/helloworld.wav`

I am trying to delete this file

```
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, successCallback, errorCallback)

        function successCallback(fs) {
            fs.root.getFile('/storage/emulated/0/myApp/helloworld.wav', {
                create: false
            }, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.remove(function() {
                    alert('File removed.');
                }, errorCallback);
            }, errorCallback);
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
        }
```

It does not delete the file and always returns `error code 1` (not found).  Can anybody help me in pointing what is wrong.

when I check from file manager,this is where my file is physically : `/storage/emulated/0/myApp/helloworld.wav` but it always return error code 1

Comment: Hi can you share the updated snippet to delete the file and not the file directory. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel the below line could be the issue,
"**window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, successCallback, errorCallback)**"

In some of the posts i read, it was mentioned that requestfilsystem method along with LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT argument will not work in android unless the device is rooted.

I made it work using - "**window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,successCallback, errorCallback);**"

If required, i can share the sample code for deleting directory along with files in it. Please let me know. Hope it helps.

Here is the sample code as per the request,

```
function clearDirectory() {

    if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
    } else {
        //for ios
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
    }
};

function onFileSystemDirSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var entry = "";
    if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
        entry = fileSystem;
    } else {
        //for ios
        entry = fileSystem.root;
    }
    entry.getDirectory("Folder_Name", {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        },
        function(entry) {
            entry.removeRecursively(function() {
                console.log("Delete successful !!!");
            }, fail);
        }, getDirFail);
};

function getDirFail(error) {
    alert("getDirFail - " + error.code);
};

function fail(error) {
    alert("fail - " + error.code);
};
```

**File creation:**

```
function writeFile() {
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
            } else {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
            }

        }    

        function onError(e) {
            alert("onError");
        };

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var entry = "";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry = fileSystem;
            } else {
                entry = fileSystem.root;
            }
            entry.getDirectory("Folder_Name", {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
        };

        function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
            dir.getFile(filename, {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
        };

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            // logic to write file in respective directory
        };

        function errorHandler(e) {
            // handle error
        }
```

Comment: LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT does work for writing files. I will try with resolveLocalFileSystemURL. You could post your code in the answer,that would be great

Comment: @LeonardoDaCodinchi, Have posted the code in my response. Please let me know if it helps

Comment: This removes the directory,not the file. When I try getFile, it throws this error ```Cannot read property 'getFile' of undefined```

Comment: @LeonardoDaCodinchi, it deletes the directory along with the file in it. interestingly, i m able to invoke getfile function for file creation in my case. Added sample snippet to my original response.

Comment: Does the file need to be stored at some specific location so that it can deleted in future? my file location is ```/storage/emulated/0/myApp/helloworld.wav```

Comment: @LeonardoDaCodinchi, if you have the file stored in the respective folder, you can go ahead and delete it. Moreover, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory will return you - "/storage/emulated/0". From there, you can navigate to the myApp folder and delete the fail or you can delete the myApp  folder itself.

Comment: Nope. I think ```cordova.file.externalRootDirectory``` points to sdcard

Comment: @LeonardoDaCodinchi i tried out in an android device which does not have sd card. In my case cordova.file.externalRootDirectory pointed to '/storage/emulated/0' But as you said even in github page of file plugin it says sd card.

Comment: Hi @Gandhi, can you add a snippet to delete a particular file. getFile returns error code 1 for your provided snippet. I don't want to delete the whole directory and its file. Just a particular file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's best if you use a plugin with native capabilities, which will save files where they should be saved and you will be guaranteed read and write access.

You can check it out here: [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

I don't know in what kind of device you are trying to use that code. In that page you can see all the different filesystem paths to different OS (Android, iOS, Blackberry, etc).

Comment: I'd love to know why the downvote, the actual correct answer used this plugin constants.. which in the original question did not.. Whoever downvoted, I'd love to know why, i'm just trying to help, and I don't think I was that wrong to get a downvote. Cheers :)

Comment: Your question ended up in the Low Quality Posts queue because it is at risk of being flagged as a 'Link only answer". Just FYI. (and no, I didn't downvote  you so I can't help there)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your explanation. Better quality for the next answers :)