# Copying Image from Photolibrary to Filesystem - Error 1000

Tags: file, cordova, camera

This is my function to select an image from the photo library using the cordova camera plugin;

```
$('#select').click(function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
                                                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL, 
                                                        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
        function onSuccess(imageURI) {

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(entry) {
                debugger;
                fs.root.getDirectory('InsectFinder', {}, function(dirEntry) {
                    debugger;
                    dirEntry.getDirectory('FundmeldungPictures', {}, function(dirDirEntry) {
                        debugger;
                        var newFileName = fundmeldungInsectId + "_" + (images.length+1) + ".jpg";                           
                        entry.copyTo(dirDirEntry, newFileName, function(newEntry) {
                            debugger;
                            var img = {name: newFileName, id: images.length+1};
                            images = images.concat(img);
                            bilderDataSource.data(images);
                            console.log("yay");
                        }, errorHandler);
                    }, errorHandler);
                }, errorHandler);
            }, errorHandler);
        }
        function onFail(message) {
            console.error('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
    });
```

The problem is, when I get to the `copyTo` function, I get an error with code 1000.
I have the same code when capturing an image with the phones camera and it works fine.

EDIT:
This is the function where I request the filesystem. I declared fs as a global variable so I can access this filesystem at different times.

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 100*1024*1024, function(filesystem) {
                console.log("opened file system: " + filesystem.name);
                fs = filesystem;

            }, errorHandler);
```

EDIT:
When I debugged the copyTo function, I think it failed at this line:

```
var messages = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(bridgeSecret, service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

messages is undefined after this function

In the error handling that follows, I get the following processMessage:

```
"S01 File1981269537 {"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"FundmeldungPictures","fullPath":"\/InsectFinder\/FundmeldungPictures","filesystemName":"persistent","filesystem":1,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/InsectFinder\/FundmeldungPictures\/"}"
```

Comment: Could be a possible permission issue. Are you testing on Anrdoid MarshMallow?

Comment: @Gandhi Yes, I have Android 6.0.1

Comment: ensure that you are using the latest version of camera plugin with all permission issues pertaining to Marshmallow and more importantly use latest version of cordova file plugin (4.2.0) released recently

Comment: @Gandhi I updated both plugins, but I still get the same error.

Comment: i guess it should be fs.getDirectory instead of fs.root.getDirectory for Android. Please have a look at this link for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037359/unable-to-delete-file-using-cordova/36038741#36038741

Comment: @Gandhi I tried it, but now I get an error, that fs.getDirectory is not a function. Everywhere else where I use the file plugin I also use fs.root.getDirectory and it works just fine.

Comment: Did u had a look at the link i sent which has the detailed code? Also  could you post the complete code as i dont see fs reference in any arguments?

Comment: Yes, I read that link. But I think, it is a different problem. Like I said, everything else I do with the file plugin works fine. It is only copying an image from the photo library which causes an error.

Comment: window.requestFileSystem dint worked for me when i tried. I got it working using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL. I still recommend you to go through the link which i sent earlier for better clarity

Comment: window.requestFileSystem worked for me. I read that sometimes there is a problem because window.requestFileSystem is undefined. But I just reload on `deviceready` and it works.
I read that link and understand what it is saying, but I have a different problem

Comment: @Gandhi I tried changing from window.requestFileSystem to window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL like in the link that you provided. But I still get the same error 1000 when I try to copy the image from the photolibrary.

Comment: could you debug the issue in chrome inspect devices and let us know where exactly is failing?

Comment: @Gandhi It is failing at the `entry.copyTo` command

Comment: any error description apart from error code? what version of camera plugin you are using? can you test it on lollipop once to narrow down the issue?

Comment: @Gandhi I added some more error information. I am using the newest version of the camera plugin rel/2.2.0. I don't have a lollipop device, so I can't test it, sorry.

Comment: after having a look at your updates, the file path seems to be the issue i guess ("fullPath":"\/InsectFinder\/FundmeldungPictures","filesystemName":"persistent","filesystem":1,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/InsectFinder\/FundmeldungPictures\/") Try using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory as in the link i sent earlier

Comment: @Gandhi I am using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory. I changed my code yesterday and it's still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109787/discussion-between-gandhi-and-adryr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by returning the `DATA_URL` of the image and writing it into a new file in my file system.