# Download Image file from server using AngularJs in mobile device

Tags: angularjs, file, cordova, plugins

I want to download images from the server in mobile device.I have added the cordova-file and cordove-file-transfer plugin. But its not working. Please help me out.

Comment: Please be more specific. Whats the error or problem you are facing?

Comment: the code which i am using is working for a web app but not works on device

Comment: Can you share the code snippet and error trace?

Comment: i am referring to this page [link](http://www.gajotres.net/using-cordova-file-transfer-plugin-with-ionic-framework/2/), it show me success in console, but I dont know where my file is downloaded

Comment: As per the link, the file is getting downloaded to cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, which is External storage (SD card) root

Comment: and what if i want to download the image file in a new folder. How to create new folder in that case?

Comment: Checkout this link which has detailed sample code related to folder and file creation

Comment: Sorry my bad. link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037359/unable-to-delete-file-using-cordova/36038741#36038741