# How to use the filesystem with cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm currently working on an Android app that uses the filesystem. I can't figure out how to use the native filesystem (the one you access if you use the `cordova-plugin-file`) How do I write and read files ?

I've looked at the [filesystem tutorial by HTML5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) but that's for chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [official repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). At the bottom, there's a pretty useful example section.

If you are searching for an API that's similar to the node.js `fs`-module than you should look at the npm package `html5-fs` which basically binds the cordova-plugin-file api to a node.js like API. (`npm install html5-fs`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check out the following [github page](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations) where i have created a basic working sample of Cordova App that interacts with native system using file plugins.

The working sample basically downloads file from URL and stores it in device by creating a folder. It allows supports delete operation. You can also check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037359/unable-to-delete-file-using-cordova/36038741#36038741) for more info. Hope it helps